# Read variable name from file and use as locator variable

Tags: robotframework

I have a file with locators which I import in my test suite. The file has lines like these:

```
LOCATOR_ABC='id=abc'
LOCATOR_XYX='id=xyz'
```

I have another file which contains locator variable names and expected values, so something like this:

```
LOCATOR_ABC¤hello world
LOCATOR_XYZ¤goodbye world
```

Now I want to loop through the latter file and do something like this for each line:

```
${locator}=    Fetch From Left     ${line}    ¤
${value}=    Fetch From Right    ${line}    ¤
${ui_value}=    Get Text    ${${locator}}
... compare value and ui_value and expect them to match ....
```

The problem is I get the error:

```
Variable '${?LOCATOR_ABC}' not found. Did you mean:
${LOCATOR_ABC}
```

I know the part with ${${locator}} is probably not nice/correct, but changing my setup so the locator¤value file has lines like this:

```
${LOCATOR_ABC}¤hello world
${LOCATOR_XYZ}¤goodbye world
```

And then use this in my test instead:

```
${ui_value}=    Get Text    ${locator}
```

The error message is:

```
ValueError: Element locator '?${LOCATOR_ABC}' did not match any elements.
```

So I guess my question is if anyone can shed some light on the ? part of the error message? What am I doing wrong? And or is there another/better way to do this?

Comment: Turns out it was a problem with the encoding of the file. Changing it to plain old ascii solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with file encoding. Changing to ascii encoding solved the problem.